# qooxdoo - custom listitem with button

Tags: button, scroll, listitem, qooxdoo

I made a custom listitem view (based on http://news.qooxdoo.org/tutorial-part-4-2-custom-widgets-4) with 2 buttons.

One button opens a new window (the url is a property of the listitem).
The second button locates the item on a map.

It works fine with the first elements of the list but if I scroll down the list with the scroll bar and click again on a button of a listitem, the url and location are wrong. I mean the url is the one from an another listitem (usually the one above).

Any help would be really appreciate.

Here is the code :

```
qx.Class.define("appli.Application",
{
  extend : qx.application.Standalone,

  members :
  {
    main : function()
    {
      this.base(arguments);
      if (qx.core.Environment.get("qx.debug"))
      {
        qx.log.appender.Native;
        qx.log.appender.Console;
      }

      //qx.theme.manager.Meta.getInstance().setTheme(qx.theme.Modern);

      var model = this.model = new qx.data.Array();
      var list = this.list = new qx.ui.list.List(model);
      list.setDecorator(null);

      this.list.setItemHeight(150);

        var delegate = {
          createItem : function() {
            return new appli.ItemView();
          },

          bindItem : function(controller, item, id) {
            controller.bindProperty("title", "post", null, item, id);
            controller.bindProperty("imageUrl", "icon", null, item, id);
            controller.bindProperty("url", "link", null, item, id);
          },

          configureItem : function(item) {
            item.getChildControl("icon").setWidth(160);
            item.getChildControl("icon").setHeight(120);
            item.getChildControl("icon").setMarginRight(6);
            //item.getChildControl("icon").setScale(true);
            item.setMinHeight(52);
          }
        };
      this.list.setDelegate(delegate);
      this.getRoot().add(this.list, {edge : 0});

      //Test with local data
      /*var data = [
                  ["Car","http://www.leboncoin.fr/voitures/553182339.htm?ca=15_s","http://193.164.196.30/thumbs/963/963318091858592.jpg"],
                  ["Game","","http://193.164.197.30/thumbs/956/956317090813867.jpg"],
                  ["Veste style imper Rouge","http://www.leboncoin.fr/vetements/553226581.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.50/thumbs/960/960318094103573.jpg"],
                  ["Lot de divers bibelots","http://www.leboncoin.fr/decoration/553226580.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.40/thumbs/960/960318090959516.jpg"],
                  ["Trotteur","http://www.leboncoin.fr/equipement_bebe/553226579.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.60/thumbs/961/961318097025582.jpg"],
                  ["Bouddha en résine - TROC 3000 TROC3000","http://www.leboncoin.fr/decoration/355911087.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.40/thumbs/963/963318096001428.jpg"],
                  ["Téléphone Analogique sans fils","http://www.leboncoin.fr/telephonie/553226578.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.40/thumbs/961/961318096589452.jpg"],
                  ["Bureau","http://www.leboncoin.fr/ameublement/553226577.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.60/thumbs/963/963318098189494.jpg"],
                  ["Appareil Fitness Abdos-Fessier- Hanches","http://www.leboncoin.fr/sports_hobbies/553226576.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.30/thumbs/964/964318093519411.jpg"],
                  ["Aire de jeux gonflable","http://www.leboncoin.fr/equipement_bebe/553226575.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.30/thumbs/963/963318091253099.jpg"],
                  ["Robe Lipsy violette taille 40 So95","http://www.leboncoin.fr/vetements/553226574.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.50/thumbs/968/968318099827570.jpg"],
                  ["Bureau en bois massif avec tiroirs","http://www.leboncoin.fr/ameublement/553226573.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.50/thumbs/968/968318094933722.jpg"],
                  ["Canapé clic clac","http://www.leboncoin.fr/ameublement/553226572.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.40/thumbs/963/963318090754017.jpg"],
                  ["Anneau bague en argent reminescence et sa pochette","http://www.leboncoin.fr/montres_bijoux/553226571.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.60/thumbs/960/960318094599407.jpg"],
                  ["Jeu de palets + dalle de plomb","http://www.leboncoin.fr/jeux_jouets/553226570.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.30/thumbs/960/960318098708467.jpg"],
                  ["Bois de chauffage sec","http://www.leboncoin.fr/bricolage/553226569.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.40/thumbs/960/960318097353553.jpg"],
                  ["Manteau garcon t9-10 ans de chez Zara","http://www.leboncoin.fr/vetements/553226568.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.50/thumbs/964/964318094104186.jpg"],
                  ["Réussir le Concours Passerelle 2","http://www.leboncoin.fr/livres/553226567.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.60/thumbs/964/964318096810766.jpg"],
                  ["Porte capsule nespresso","http://www.leboncoin.fr/arts_de_la_table/553226565.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.30/thumbs/968/968318093179824.jpg"],
                  ["Lot de pulls de grossesse","http://www.leboncoin.fr/vetements/553226564.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.30/thumbs/969/969318094345851.jpg"],
                  ["Poussette trois roue","http://www.leboncoin.fr/equipement_bebe/553226563.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.50/thumbs/960/960318099320949.jpg"],
                  ["Lot 9 bodys 18 mois","http://www.leboncoin.fr/vetements_bebe/553226562.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.60/thumbs/963/963318097981206.jpg"],
                  ["pull promod","http://www.leboncoin.fr/vetements/553226561.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.30/thumbs/966/966318091577576.jpg"],
                  ["Robe t.xs marque benetton","http://www.leboncoin.fr/vetements/553226560.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.40/thumbs/967/967318090362940.jpg"],
                  ["Chemise homme napapijri xxl","http://www.leboncoin.fr/vetements/489677448.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.60/thumbs/968/968318095631775.jpg"],
                  ["Ampli akai rx-v 357","http://www.leboncoin.fr/image_son/468870018.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.30/thumbs/961/961318097647320.jpg"],
                  ["Grosse pelote rose 210 gr aspect mohair","http://www.leboncoin.fr/sports_hobbies/381151108.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.60/thumbs/962/962318094347598.jpg"],
                  ["Location maison bourg Nanteuil en Vallée","http://www.leboncoin.fr/locations/553226559.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.50/thumbs/967/967318098127277.jpg"],
                  ["Lot de vêtements bébé garçon 6 mois: 35 pièces","http://www.leboncoin.fr/vetements_bebe/553226558.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.40/thumbs/967/967318098074684.jpg"],
                  ["Lemax manège zinger","http://www.leboncoin.fr/decoration/553226557.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.40/thumbs/967/967318098002537.jpg"],
                  ["Pierrade de marque tefal","http://www.leboncoin.fr/electromenager/553226556.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.60/thumbs/968/968318090030679.jpg"],
                  ["Lustre Turquoise","http://www.leboncoin.fr/decoration/553226555.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.60/thumbs/962/962318092733887.jpg"],
                  ["Aire de jeux","http://www.leboncoin.fr/equipement_bebe/553226554.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.40/thumbs/965/965318096816865.jpg"],
                  ["Cuisinière gaz / électrique avec tourne broche","http://www.leboncoin.fr/electromenager/553226553.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.197.50/thumbs/964/964318096264301.jpg"],
                  ["Canape d'angle avec Table Basse et Tapis","http://www.leboncoin.fr/decoration/553226551.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.40/thumbs/963/963318092977145.jpg"],
                  ["Bourriquet bleu en velours","http://www.leboncoin.fr/equipement_bebe/553226549.htm?ca=12_s","http://193.164.196.30/thumbs/968/968318090336920.jpg"]
                  ];
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    this.list.getModel().push(new appli.Item(data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2],""));
                }*/

      //Test with XHR Request
         var req = new qx.io.request.Xhr("http://cartorion.appspot.com/lbcfeed?q=&o=1&location=&category=velos&region=toutes&dept=tous");
            req.setAsync(true);
                req.addListener("success", function(e) {

                    var resp = e.getTarget().getResponse();
                    var lines = resp.split('\n');
                    for (var i=0;i<lines.length-1;i++){
                        var values = lines[i].split(",");
                        //var myitem = new appli.model.Item(values[0],values[1],parseFloat(values[2]),values[3],new Date(values[6]),values[5],values[4]);
                        this.list.getModel().push(new appli.Item(values[0],values[5],values[4],""));

                    }

                },this);
        req.send();
    }
  }
});


qx.Class.define("appli.Item", {
  extend : qx.core.Object,

  construct : function (title,url,imageUrl,latlng){
        this.base(arguments);
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setUrl(url);
        this.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
        this.setLatlng(latlng);
    },

    properties : {
        /**
         * Nom de carte
         */
        title : {
            check : "String",
            event : "changeTitle",
            init : ""
        },

        imageUrl : {
            check : "String",
            event : "changeImageUrl",
            init : ""
        },

        url : {
            check : "String",
            event : "changeUrl",
            init : ""
        },

        latlng : {
            check : "String",
            event : "changeLatlng",
            init : ""
        }
    }
});


qx.Class.define("appli.ItemView",  {
  extend : qx.ui.core.Widget,
  include : [qx.ui.form.MModelProperty],

  construct : function()
  {
    this.base(arguments);
    this.set({
        paddingTop:14,
        paddingLeft:4,
        maxHeight : 130
    });
    var border= new qx.ui.decoration.Single();
    border.setBottom(1,"dashed","#BBBBBB");
    this.setDecorator(border);

    // initialize the layout and allow wrap for "post"
    var layout = new qx.ui.layout.Grid(2, 2);
    layout.setColumnFlex(1, 1);
    this._setLayout(layout);

    // create the widgets
    this._createChildControl("icon");
    this._createChildControl("post");
    this._createChildControl("link");
  },

  properties :
  {

    icon :
    {
      check : "String",
      apply : "_applyIcon",
      nullable : true
    },

    post :
    {
      check : "String",
      apply : "_applyPost",
      nullable : true
    },

    link :
    {
      check : "String",
      apply : "_applyLink",
      nullable : true
    },

    latlng :
    {
      check : "String",
      apply : "_applyLink",
      nullable : true
    }   

  },

  members :
  {
    // overridden
    _createChildControlImpl : function(id)
    {
      var control;

      switch(id)
      {
        case "icon":
          control = new qx.ui.basic.Image(this.getIcon());
          control.setAnonymous(true);
          this._add(control, {row: 0, column: 0, rowSpan: 2});
          break;


        case "post":
          control = new qx.ui.basic.Label(this.getPost());
          control.setAnonymous(true);
          control.setRich(true);
          this._add(control, {row: 0, column: 1});
          break;

        case "link":
            control = new qx.ui.container.Composite(new qx.ui.layout.HBox());
            control.setMinHeight(200);
            var details = new qx.ui.form.Button("See details").set({
                maxWidth:120,
                maxHeight:25,
                marginRight:6
            });
            details.addListener("execute",function(){
                window.open(this.getLink());
            },this);
            control.add(details);

            var locate = new qx.ui.form.Button("See on map").set({
                    maxWidth:120,
                    maxHeight:25,
                    marginRight:6
                });
            locate.addListener("execute",function(){
                    //Do something with this.getLatlng()
                },this);
                control.add(locate);

            this._add(control, {row: 1, column: 1});
            break;

      }

      return control || this.base(arguments, id);
    },

    _applyIcon : function(value, old) {
      var icon = this.getChildControl("icon");
      icon.setSource(value);
    },

    _applyPost : function(value, old)
    {
      var post = this.getChildControl("post");
      post.setValue("<b>"+value+"</b>");
    },

    _applyLink : function(value, old)
    {
      var link = this.getChildControl("link");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Your widget code is broken (some 'case' not properly closed). I suggest you come up with a minimal example that runs in http://playground.qooxdoo.org and exhibits the behavior you're concerned about. Then post the link to it here.

Comment: @ThomasH Thanks to answer. The shorten url didn't work in the Qooxdoo plaground. But I updated the code and now you can copy and paste all the code in the playground. You should see my problem... It seems to work with the qx.theme.Modern (just uncomment the line in the main function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you can fix it with:

```
list.setPadding(0);
// OR
list.setFocusable(false);
```

I'm currently not sure what the root cause is, but I will strip down your example and file a bug at our [bugzilla](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/).